# Power BI Desktop Import data limitation

Tags: analytics, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I use Power BI Import (Connect to SQL Server and select Import) to get data to Power BI Desktop, is there a data volume limitation?

I know for DirectQuery there is no data volume limitation. What about Import? Is it 1GB?

Answer (score 4):

Import Data method has the size limitation of 1GB per model. So without using Power BI Premium, this method is not so much Scale-able.

The very first assumption that you might get after reading above explanation about Import Data is that; if you have a database with 100GB, then if you import it into Power BI, you will get 100GB file size in Power BI. This is not true. Power BI leverages compression engine of xVelocity and works on a Column-store in-memory technology. Column store in-memory technology compresses data and stores it in a compressed format. Sometimes you might have a 1GB Excel file, and when you import it into Power BI, your Power BI file ends up with only 10MB. This is mainly because of compression engine of Power BI. However, the compression rate is not always that. This depends on many things; the number of unique values in the column, sometimes data types and many other situations. I will write a post later that explains the compression engine in details.

Short read for this part is: Power BI will store compressed data. The size of data in Power BI would be much smaller than its size in the data source.

http://radacad.com/directquery-live-connection-or-import-data-tough-decision

Answer (score 2):

**Import Mode Limitations in Power BI**

- Depends on the imported data size, A lot of consumed memory and disk space
- On your machine (during the implementation),
- On the online/on-prem server (when it published).
- The Power BI file size can’t be bigger than 1 GB.
- You will get an error If the file size is bigger than 1 GB, in this case, you must have the Power BI Premium that allows having 50 GB file size.
- No recent data without a refresh.

> For more details, please, check **[Power BI: Switch from Import to DirectQuery Mode](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/switch-import-to-directquery-mode-powerbi/)**